Next.js redirecting didn't change the page somitimes
I have some problems with redirecting in the next.js server components. I have login middleware and the main component which also has pretty simple logic. What I do on the login page is save the token to the cookie and redirect the user to the main component. I also have middleware to check if the user can go to main page or login(in case of already logged in) or not. And I have logout component too which is simply deletes the cookie and sends back to the login with the (router.replace(/login)). And in this situation when I do log in sometimes(not always) it send the query to backend works good come back with the result but it didn't sends me to the main component somehow. And in the network i notice there is some querys such as "url/login?_rsc=1wtp7" . And I found out it's the redirect query which next done if we use redirect in the server component. I tested in both dev and production mode both have this problem. But I am unable to find out why this happening. I hope I cleared out my situation fully. Thanks for the answers.
//Login.tsx
const response = await fetch(
      `${BASE_URL}/login/`,
      {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        body: JSON.stringify({ username, password }),
      }
    );
    let respBody = await response.json();

    if (response.ok) {
      localStorage.setItem("token", respBody.token);
      await storeToken(respBody);
      // showing success toast
      toast.success("You are logged in");
      router.push("/");
    } else {
      toast.error(respBody.detail || "Failed to login");
      // showing error toast and resetting the fields
      setLoading(false);
      reset();
    }

//Middleware.ts
import {NextResponse, type NextRequest} from 'next/server'

export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
    const currentUser = request.cookies.get('accessToken')?.value
    const redirectToLogin = new URL(request.url).searchParams.get('forceLogin');


    if (redirectToLogin === 'true') {
          const response = NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/login', request.url))
          response.cookies.set('accessToken', '', { expires: new Date(0) })
          return response
    }

    if (!currentUser && !request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/login')) {
        return Response.redirect(new URL('/login', request.url))
    }
    if (currentUser && request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/login')) {
        return Response.redirect(new URL('/', request.url))
    }
}

export const config = {
    matcher: ['/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|.*\\.png$).*)'],
}

//storeToken.ts

export async function storeToken(request: StoreTokenRequest) {
    cookies().set({
        name: "accessToken",
        value: request.token,
        httpOnly: true,
        sameSite: "strict",
        secure: true,
    })

    cookies().set({
        name: "refreshToken",
        value: request.refresh_token,
        httpOnly: true,
        sameSite: "strict",
        secure: true,
    })
}

I wanted it immediately send me to the main component but sometimes it failed and stopped like this untill I refresh the page and login again.
